# Transform data in ksql

Tags: apache-kafka, transform, ksqldb

I am trying to convert data from one format to another format (one schema to another schema).

Example :

```
payload = {
    'a' : 'a1',
    'b' : 'b1'
}
```

and i want to transform this payload into another form let us say

```
payload_transform = {
   'a':{
      'b' : 'b1'
    }
    'c' : 'a1'
}
```

consider that data(`payload`) is coming from Kafka, i want to see `payload_transform` in consumer that with transformation

is it possible with ksql ?

**Updated :**

Can we do one level :

```
payload = {
    'a' : 'a1',
    'b' : 'b1'
}
```

to

```
payload = {
    'confluent' : 'a1',
    'b' : 'b1'
}
```

and can we add conditions ?

For example :  if **'b'** key present in payload generate

```
payload = {
        'confluent' : 'a1',
        'b' : 'b1'
    }
```

otherwise :

```
payload = {
        'kafka' : 'a1',
        'b' : 'b1'
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst KSQL does support un-nesting JSON (with `EXTRACTJSONFIELD`), it does not currently (March 2018 / version 0.5) support building nested structures. It also does not currently support nested Avro.

*Updated response to updated question*:

- You can rename fields, simply using the SQL `AS` clause:

  `SELECT A AS NEW_COL, B FROM INPUT_STREAM`

Can you describe more about what you're trying to do here? Renaming a field conditionally doesn't make sense in the example you've given. Perhaps also give KSQL a try and see what works for you.

Comment: Thanks Robin, Can u answer for updated section too. it will helpful a lot.

Comment: In our case we've have huge transformations, like converting one JSON to another JSON(example one schema to another schema), and condition based transformation too.